# mobile safari - reliable callback for when Image loads?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari

I try to load an image as such:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'mars.png';
img.onLoad = callback;


function callback(){
    // doesnt fire
       alert("loaded");
}
```

the callback never fires, whats the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST define the onload BEFORE you change the src and event handlers are lowercase so it is spelled onload

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = callback;
img.src = 'mars.png';

function callback(){
  alert("loaded");
}
```

or as I prefer it

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
  alert("loaded");
}
img.src = 'mars.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these?

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'mars.png';
img.onLoad = function(){
    // doesnt fire
       alert("loaded");
};
```

Comment: doesn't fire, both on mobile and desktop safari, and chrome too it seems

Answer (score 0):

mplungjan is right you can use these instead:

```
img.onload = function(){
    // doesnt fire
       alert("loaded");
};
```

with lower **l** in **onLoad**

Comment: What do you mean by "with lower l in onLoad"?

Comment: That you should use onload instead of onLoad

Comment: Haha, seems obvious now, can't wait your reply in 2018 tho

Comment: Let see. This is just to remember to put somethign in 2018